# CMake: 'AUTOMOC' feature skips sources of executable targets?

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, executable, moc

There is a medium-sized project with a top level `CMakeLists.txt` which defines some common stuff and invokes the configuration of all artifacts (subprojects) in the project like this:

```
add_subdirectory(components/A)
add_subdirectory(components/B)
add_subdirectory(components/C)

add_subdirectory(components/E)
```

Artifacts are static/shared libraries or executables (which somehow depend on each other). In this example, there is only one executable: `E`. Everything configures and builds perfectly fine when plain old `qt4_wrap_cpp` is used to process MOC.

When switching to the (relatively) new **[AUTOMOC](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#prop_tgt%3aAUTOMOC)** feature by adding the following to the top `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
```

all the sources of static/shared libraries are `AUTOMOC`'ed just fine. However, the sources of executable target (`E` in this example) are never `AUTOMOC`'ed.

I've tried both `MSYS Makefiles` and `Ninja` generators, and both simply do not create the target for `AUTOMOC`'ing, but only for executable's sources (for static/shared library targets `AUTOMOC`'ing target is added).

- Has anyone experienced that already?
- What could be the cause?
- Does that smell like a bug?

### Update

---

I found the cause, the discussion is on [CMake mailing list](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2013-April/054628.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To summarize, the problem was that `E` didn't include Qt module neither explicitly:

```
find_package(Qt4 ...)
```

nor implicitly:

```
find_package(MyPrecious ...)
```

where `MyPrecious` could be some 3rd party module which includes Qt by itself.

As a result, non-cached variables like `QT_VERSION_*` are not present in the scope of `E` subproject, and for that reason `AUTOMOC` feature cannot function properly. Nasty pitfall I'd say. For more details refer to [CMake mailing list](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2013-April/054628.html).